# Trying to setup full screen particle.js with fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js, particles

I wanted the [particles.js](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) to appear all over the screen in the first section, but whatever I do, they are under other parts of the page. I added the particles in second section. It seems to me this is through the use of fullPage.js(Alvaro Trigo, cant post more than 2 links, sry). I'm attaching my website and I'd like someone to take a look at this. [unlikemenow.github.io](http://unlikemenow.github.io) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

So first off, try putting the `particles-js`class on a `<canvas>` element instead of a `<div>`.

That means your first section will be wrapped in the `<div class = "section">` like you already have, with the direct child being `<canvas class = "particles-js">`. Give that `<canvas>` a unique id like `<canvas id = "the-particles" class = "particles-js">`.

In CSS, assign a `Z-Index` to the `#theParticles` ID. Then set a `Z-Index` on your `.section` class. Make sure that the `Z-Index` on the `<canvas>` is higher than the `<div>`. I haven'ted tested this myself, so if it doesn't work, let me know, I can code through it for you. I've also never worked with particles-js before but it looks super cool!

Comment: Hey, thanks for respond. I followed your instructions but failed. Canva is created in canva and nothing is displayed. I think it is because of fullPage.css but I cant solve it. Yeah, it is cool. Also this nav isn't mine :)

Comment: Did you write `<canva>` or `<canvas>`? ;) also sorry, I tried my best to think it through without coding through it

Comment: canvas :P its ok